# Python 3.9 in Statsmodel ImportError: cannot import name 'Literal' from 'statsmodels.compat.python'

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror, statsmodels, python-3.9

I cannot manage to import ARIMA model from statsmodels without encountering this error:

This is how the import is:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA
```

This is the error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Literal' from 'statsmodels.compat.python' (C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\compat\python.py)
```

I have already tried to uninstall, re-install and update it, but that does not change. Please help me solve the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

Importing ARIMA from `arima_model` instead of `arima.model`:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
```

https://www.statsmodels.org/0.8.0/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA.html